Find the expectation of the random variable $X^3$ when $X$ is a uniform random variable in $(0,1)$ following this particular way of reasoning.
Find the expectation of the random variable $X^3$ when $X$ is a uniform random variable in $(0,1).$
I tried solving the problem as follows:
$X$ is a uniform random variable (URV) implies that, if $f_X$ is the probability density function of $X$ then, $f_X:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ such that $f_X(x)=1,x\in (0,1)$ and $f_X(x)= 0,x\notin (0,1).$
Now, $E[X^3]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X^3}(x)dx,\tag 1$ where $f_{X^3}$ is the probability density function of $Y=X^3.$
We don't know what's $f_Y.$
We note that,
If $F_Y$and $F_X$ are the cumulative distribution function (cdf) of $Y$ and $X$ then,
$F_Y(a)=P(X^3\leq a)=P(X\leq a^{\frac 13}=F(a^{\frac 13})=\int_{-\infty}^{a^{\frac 13}}f_Xdx.$
If $0\leq a\leq 1\implies a^{\frac 13}\in (0,1),$ then, $f_X(a)=1.$ So, $F_Y(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{a^{\frac 13}}f_Xdx=\int_{0}^{a^{\frac 13}}dx=a^{\frac 13}.$
If $a\leq 0$ then, $f_X(a)=0.$ So, $F_Y(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{a^{\frac 13}}f_Xdx=\int_{0}^{a^{\frac 13}}0dx=0.$
If $a\geq 1$ then, $f_X(a)=0.$ So, $F_Y(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{a^{\frac 13}}f_Xdx=\int_{0}^{a^{\frac 13}}0dx=0.$
Thus, we can say that,
$$
F_Y(a) =
\begin{array}{ll}
    0 & \text{if } a \leq 0, \\
    a^{\frac 13} & \text{if } a\in (0,1), \\
    1 & \text{if } a \geq 1.
\end{array}
$$
Also, we have, $F_Y(a)=\int_{-\infty}^af_Y(x)dx\implies F_Y'(a)=f_Y(a),\forall a\in \Bbb R.$
This means, $f_Y:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ such that, $f_Y(x)=\frac{13}a^{-\frac 23},\forall x\in (0,1).$
Also, $f_Y(x)=0,\forall x\in \Bbb R\setminus [0,1].$

However, as we can see that, $F_Y$ is not differentiable at $x=0,1.$ This is the reason why, I am unable to find $f_Y(x)$ at $x=0,1$ since my method of finding $f_Y$ was simply to use the formula $f_Y(a)=F_Y'(a).$ Now, as $F_Y'(a)$ at $0,1$ doesn't exist I don't know of any other way(s) to actually calculate the value of $f_Y$ at the points $0,1.$
If I were able to find $f_Y$ at all points, then using the formula $(1)$ we can easily obtain our desired result. So, precisely, I want to know how to calculate $f_Y(0)$ and $f_Y(1)$ ?
Note: I know there are various other ways to calculate $E[X^3],$ but I  specifically interested in using this way of reasoning to calculate $E[X^3].$
Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

The CDF of $Y=X^3$ is
$$
F(y)=\mathbb P{X^3\le y}=\mathbb P{X\le \sqrt[3]{y}}=\sqrt[3]{y},,\quad y\in[0,1],.
$$
The PDF of $X^3$ is
$$
f(y)=\frac1{3y^{2/3}},,\quad y\in(0,1],.
$$
Since $Y=X^3$ is a continuous random variable we don't have to worry about its PDF at single points. Therefore,
$$
\mathbb E[X^3]=\int_0^1yf(y),dy=\frac13\int_0^1y^{1/3},dy=\frac14,.
$$

Use that
$$\mathbb{E}(X^3)=\int_0^1x^3f_X(x)\ dx=\int_0^1x^3\ dx=\left.\frac{x^4}{4}\right|^1_0=\frac{1}{4}$$
In general, if $X$ is an absolute continuous random variable with density function $f_X$ supported on a set $D$ and $g$ is a sufficiently regular function (at least measurable), then you have:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[g(X)\right]=\int_D g(x)f_X(x)\ dx$$
In your case, $g(x)=x^3$ which is continuous.

OP was specifcally interested in the more cumbersome way to use the PDF of $Y=X^3.$
